# Opening webpage in javascript on trigger

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

I'm using a script called "HIT Scraper WITH EXPORT" to help me with my job. Right now it's set up in a way that any time there is a new posting the page plays a audible sound/ding. Normally when this happens I have to switch tabs and manually click on the new listing to preview it. I'm trying to make it so it automatically opens the listing before/after dinging. Also if possible having it put focus on that tab if I'm in a different one. Is any of this possible, where should I start? I'll post the code and some areas of interest I noticed, I just don't know what to do with these areas.. Thank you in advance.

The function that runs when a new hit is found I think:

```
function newHits(dingNoise) {
    //console.log(dingNoise);
    if (dingNoise || newHitDing)
        document.getElementById("ding_noise"+audio_index).play();
}
```

I think "preview_link" is the var I need to automatically open after the ding sound plays.

```
var preview_link = "/mturk/preview?groupId=" + group_ID;
```

So my logic was something like:

```
function newHits(dingNoise) {
    //console.log(dingNoise);
    if (dingNoise || newHitDing)
        document.getElementById("ding_noise"+audio_index).play();
    window.open("/mturk/preview?groupId=") + group_ID;

}
```

Which did not work.. Here's the full script if anyone has any ideas.. Thanks again.

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/2002-hit-scraper-with-export/code

EDIT: I don't think the way I originally wanted to do this will work, nothing in the code knows/points to the actual new listings. All that's defined in the code is the preview link function. If there is some way to have it call/open that "var preview_link = "/mturk/preview?groupId=" + group_ID;" after the ding, that would probably be what I need.

```
for (var j = 0; j < $requester.length; j++)
{
    var $hits = $requester.eq(j).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('td[class="capsule_field_text"]');
    var requester_name = $requester.eq(j).text().trim();
    var requester_link = $requester.eq(j).attr('href');
    var group_ID=(listy[j] ? listy[j] : "");
    group_ID=group_ID.replace("/mturk/notqualified?hit","");
    var masters = false;
    var title = $title.eq(j).text().trim();
    var preview_link = "/mturk/preview?groupId=" + group_ID;
    //console.log(listy[j]);
    //console.log(title+" "+group_ID +" "+ listy[j]);
    if (!group_ID || group_ID.length == 0){
        preview_link = requester_link;
        title += " (Requester link substituted)";
    }
    var reward = $reward.eq(j).text().trim();
    var hits = $hits.eq(4).text().trim();
    var time = $times.eq(j).parent()[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML;
    var description = $descriptions.eq(j).parent()[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML;
    //console.log(description);
    var requester_id = requester_link.replace('/mturk/searchbar?selectedSearchType=hitgroups&requesterId=','');
    var accept_link;
    accept_link = preview_link.replace('preview','previewandaccept');
```

Comment: You can't tell browser to focus a new tab. Think about it ... if everyone did that you would totally lose control of your browser as a user

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to do:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.host + '/mturk/preview?groupId='+ group_ID)
```

I'm actually not sure if you need the `window.location.host +` part.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't change anything, just bugged the screen out.